# How to run a function without using any functions defined in the script in Lua

Tags: lua

I am trying to loadstring a string and run it as a function. Here is my problem:

```lua
a = "hello"
loadstring("print(a)")()
```

I dont want the code above to use any vars/funcs outside of it. My goal is to make the script above print nil since a isnt defined inside the loadstring.

Sorry if the question is very brief. It was hard to explain my problem.

Comment: @Joseph Sible-Reinstate Monica sorry my bad. I meant to have a global var not local.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your variable `a` lives in the global environment. To keep your chunk from seeing it, you need to give it a different environment. In Lua 5.1, you'd do that like this:

```
a = "hello"
local chunk = loadstring("print(a)")
setfenv(chunk, {print = print})
chunk()
```

In Lua 5.2 or newer, you'd do that like this:

```
a = "hello"
load("print(a)", nil, "t", {print = print})()
```

It's important to note that `print` isn't magic. It won't be in the new environment unless you put it there explicitly, like I did.

Comment: Thank you so much!
I do still have a problem. What if this said string was dynamic. I don't know what is going to be executed. Will I have to define every single LuaU (Roblox Lua) function?

Comment: @Cottient You could do tricks like deep-copying `_G` and then removing what you don't want, but this is really starting to sound like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/386992). What are you actually trying to achieve by restricting a script like this? Could you just use `local`s instead, like you did when you first posted the question?

Comment: What I am trying to achieve is something like a script editor. The user types the code and presses execute. Think of it as a command line. If there are no other solutions then I guess I will just make everything local.

Comment: @Cottient In that case, that's definitely what you should do. Good practice when writing Lua is that everything should always be local unless you have a good reason for it to not be. In this case you don't, and in fact you have a good reason for it to be.